# Django don't refresh site when form is invalid

Tags: python, json, django, forms

I am currently developing a website for which I use a lot of modals with forms in them. The thing is, every time I enter invalid information in a form field and press the submit button, the modal just closes and there is no indication that the form was invalid.

I already know that there is the possibility of making an ajax request which sends the form data to another view which then responds with a JSONResponse that contains errors which can then be displayed(like shown in this article: https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/). That would work but by doing that I would lose all benefits of django forms. Because I have to submit the form data as JSON, I cant use functions like form.is_valid.

So my question is: Is there a way to not refresh the site when a invalid form is submitted and displaying errors without having to send the data via JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit HTML form a browser navigates you to the URL that you specify in that form's `action` attribute. There is no way to implement HTML form submission without the navigation to the `action` URL.

So your only choice is an AJAX request.

> Because I have to submit the form data as JSON, I cant use functions like form.is_valid.

That's not true, you call `form.is_valid` on the backend side, both HTML form and AJAX send HTTP request to your backend.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it out and actually works like a charm. Don't know why I didn't try it earlier